# Database [mysql2] not configured,laravel >5

Tags: mysql, laravel-5

I try to make 2 connections to a database in laravel. I always get:

> error database [] not configured.

Pls help me master.

This is my controller:

```
class DashboardController extends Controller
{
    public function index(request $request)
    {

        $tes = DB::connection('mysql2')->select('SELECT * from hari');
        // $tes = tes::find(1);
        dd($tes);
    }


---env--
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=crud55
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

DB_DATABASE_2=db_susantokun
DB_USERNAME_2=root
DB_PASSWORD_2=

------------database.php
'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
            'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
            ]) : [],
        ],

        'mysql2' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE_2', 'db_susantokun'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME_2', 'root'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD_2', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
            'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
            ]) : [],
        ],
```

This error occurs when calling *http://localhost:8000/dashboard*

> this is InvalidArgumentException
>   Database [mysql2] not configured.

how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You may have to rebuild the configuration cache. Run the following command in your laravel root directory:

```
php artisan config:cache
```

Answer (score 0):

after chnage .env file you should restart `php artisan serve` service